# Simulate menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, sencha-architect

I have a menu with 3 items. If a certain condition is true I want to simulate a item click before the page is rendered, like setting the default action to be selected. I create my menu dynamically.

```
Store.each(function(n) {
    var rec = n;

        var menuItem = new Ext.menu.Item({
            text: rec.data.name,
            value: rec.data.url,

        });

        Menu.add(menuItem);

        //if some condition set item as if it was clicked(selected)

});
```

I want to set a certain item inside a menu to be active as if it was clicked.

Comment: Are you trying to actually click the menu item, or just have it highlighted?

Comment: Click it as if it was selected

Comment: Please see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `.fireEvent()` method you can fire a `click` event on the menu item.

So,

```
if(some condition){
    menuItem.fireEvent('click');
}
```

Additionally, you will need a listener in the menuItem to catch this event

```
var menuItem = new Ext.menu.Item({
    text: "menu Item",
    listeners:{
        click:function(){ alert("you clicked the menu item"); }   
    }
});
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Lpg7/

Finally, I would like to add that `fireEvent()` my not be totally necessary.  Since the menuItem has a `handler` config, you could simply define a function elsewhere, and use it as the menuItem handler as well as calling it when the condition is true.

```
var myClickFunction = function(){ alert("cooler way"); }

var menuItem = new Ext.menu.Item({
    text: "menu Item",
    handler:myClickFunction
});

if(some condition){
    myClickFunction();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to fire the event.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why being under a button is a problem? If you use the second method mentioned it should not matter where the menu (or menuItem) is.

Comment: What I meant was a menu button with a menu inside